# Can't install scala and sbt using Ansible

Tags: scala, ubuntu, ansible, sbt, sdkman

I aim to install Scala and SBT on a GCP VM running Ubuntu 20.04, utilizing Ansible for automation. Despite multiple attempts, I haven't managed to achieve this goal

**First Attempt**: Using SDKMAN

Initially, I followed the instructions outlined on the [SDKMAN website](https://sdkman.io/install) to install Scala. Below is the Ansible playbook I used:

```
- name: Setup environment on machines
  hosts: machines
  become: true
  vars:
    username: "{{ user_name }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Install git
      apt:
        name: git
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install unzip and zip
      apt:
        name:
          - unzip
          - zip
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install sdkman and its dependencies
      become: true
      shell: |
        curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        

    - name: Install Scala 2.12.8 using sdkman
      become: true
      shell: |
        source "/home/{{ username }}/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
        sdk install scala 2.12.8
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

After running the `ansible-playbook` command, the following error appeared:

```
"stderr": "/bin/bash: /home/my_user_name/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh: No such file or directory
```

Remarkably, when I SSH into the machine, executing these commands poses no issue.

---

**Second Attempt**: Modified SDKMAN Approach

A similar approach was taken by following a [gist](https://gist.github.com/emilio2hd/c910661bff37246bee17). I encountered the same error as in my first attempt.

---

**Third Attempt**: Manual Installation

Next, I tried a manual installation as described [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/installing-scala-sbt-on-ubuntu-part-3-fd08fec70946). The Ansible playbook for this method is as follows:

```
  tasks:

    - name: Install git
      apt:
        name: git
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install unzip and zip
      apt:
        name:
          - unzip
          - zip
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install Scala
      apt:
        name: scala
        state: present

    - name: Add SBT repository key
      shell: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" --recv 0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823

    - name: Add SBT repository
      shell: echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list

    - name: Update apt cache
      apt:
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install SBT
      apt:
        name: sbt
        state: present
```

In this case, I got:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

---

**Fourth attempt** - use a dedicated role

Lastly, I tried using [a specialized role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/Comcast/sdkman) with the following configuration:

```
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: Comcast.sdkman
      sdkman_user: sudo
      
      sdkman_auto_answer: true
      sdkman_update: true
      sdkman_install_packages:
        - { candidate: scala, version: '2.12.8' }
        - { candidate: sbt, version: '1.9.4' }
```

But I'm getting:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "set -o pipefail\ngetent passwd sudo | cut -d: -f6\n", "delta": "0:00:00.007774", "end": "2023-09-28 19:27:22.770244", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2023-09-28 19:27:22.762470", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```